# Multiple references to Entity within a single Aggregate Root confronts the delete and insert methodology

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I have an aggregate root that has 2 entities. One of them also references the other. Due to a foreign key constraints between those entities in the database, when Spring Data JDBC deletes and tries to re-insert the data, I get `Key (department_id)=(0DJ61WH12EDHH) is not present in table "departments"`.

To check my logical structure I am thinking that:

- deleting an `Organization` should delete all `Department`s and all `Membership`s (not the `User`s, though)
- deleting a `Department` should not be possible until it is being referenced by `Membership`
- deleting a `Membership` should not delete potentially present `Department` (and obviously not the `Organization)

Here's the structure:

```
class Organization { // the aggregate root
  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @MappedCollection(idColumn = "organization_id")
  private Set<Department> departments = new HashSet<>();

  @MappedCollection(idColumn = "organization_id")
  private Set<Membership> memberships = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
class Department {
  @Id
  private Integer id;
}
```

```
class Membership {
  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @Column("organization_id")
  private AggregateReference<Organization, String> organization;

  @Column("user_id")
  private AggregateReference<User, String> user;

  @Column("department_id")
  private AggregateReference<Department, String> department;
}
```

So a `Membership` is always a combination of `Organization` and a `User`, and only sometimes a `Department` is added. When I do a change on the aggregate root, all the underlying entities get deleted, as expected, however the `Membership` is inserted before the `Department`, hence the Foreign Key constraint becomes broken.

If I dropped the constraint things work ok, but I obviously don't want to do that. Is there any workaround?

I tried to drop the constraint, to check if it would work out and it does.

I also tried having the reference between the `Membership` and `Department` as an `Entity` reference, but that didn't work out, and I guess it goes against DDD.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with some rules about DDD and Spring Data JDBC:

- `AggregateReference` is intended for references between aggregates.
- entities within an aggregate must not get referenced from outside the aggregate.

That said, I'd think `Organization`, `Department`, and `Membership` should all be separate aggregates.

Comment: But a `Department` only makes sense if there's an `Organization`. If I deleted an `Organization`, I'd like all ` Department`s  deleted (actually all "attached" `Membership`'s too). Does DDD handle a situatuon where where an aggregate only exist in the context of another aggregate?